# Microsoft Word 2013 Macro - Adding Content Controls to Multiple Items

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I need to do is add a Rich Text Content Control to all "xx"'s in a large word document.

I saw a similar thread on highlighting multiple instances. I based the solution that I've tried so far on this:

```
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "target1"
    .Replacement.Text = "target1"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Now just testing in word to see what command it uses to add the content controls individually I found this command:

```
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
```

What I came up with was:

```
    Sub StandardLanguageVariableSearch()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "xx"
    .Replacement.Text = "xx"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Swapping out `Selection.Range` with `Selection.Find` simply resulted in a "method or data field not found" or something like that. I think `Range` refers to the currently highlighted range of characters, whereas `find` refers to whatever the `with` block... well, finds.

Whatever `find` is doesn't appear to have the ability to throw some content controls onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
Sub StandardLanguageVariableSearch()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "xx"
    '.Replacement.Text = "xx"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

Do While Selection.Find.Execute

    'Selection.Text = "" 'uncomment if you want to remove xx
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)

Loop
End Sub
```